# Email Change - InvalidToken

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have scaffolded account manage pages at blazor server app. Unfortunately, when I try to change the user email (Identity/Account/Manage/Email), link that is generated seems to be not correct.

```
var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
var code = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, Input.NewEmail);
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
              "/Account/ConfirmEmailChange",
              pageHandler: null,
              values: new { userId = userId, email = Input.NewEmail, code = code },
              protocol: Request.Scheme);
              await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                        Input.NewEmail,
                        "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

When I use that link invalid token error is generated. The worse is that I have no idea how I can investigate that problem. All other links (password reset, confirmation email after registration) works correctly. Maybe that is connected with fact that the user class is extended by a few additional fields. Still, I don't have an idea about the next steps.

```
 public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
 {
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     //ect..
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"code" at that method is wrongly decoded (Base64)

```
public class ConfirmEmailChangeModel : PageModel {

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId,string email,string code)
{
 /*...* 
code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
var result = await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, email, code);
/*..*/
}
}
```

after removing that line everything is working correctly!
What is surprising for me is that line was generated by VS!
Also why it works for anyone else? That shouldn't work for anyone!

Comment: Do you use SendGrid as your SMTP provider ? If so, my code needed some adjustment. Anyhow, I'm glad you've solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you @enet. It is true that I'm using SendGrid but that was not related to that. I checked that at the debugger. Looks that at code generated by VS is not correct and that line makes problems: code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));

Comment: +1 Had the same experience. Additionally, also the email shown as the new email in the input box after sending the confirmation is IMO wrong, should be the new and not the old email. In the authenticator configuration I experienced also some odd bugs. The scaffolded pages seem to be pretty disorderly. I hope that this does not concern the security of the default identity UI in general.